# Why is shaft work equal to $VdP$?

Tags: thermodynamics, work

Mathematically it makes sense to me, because there is -PdV work occurring plus you must account for the change in flow work [d(PV)], so -PdV + PdV + VdP = VdP.  However, I'm having a difficult time conceptualizing how expansion work and a change in flow work both create shaft work.

Comment: The flow work to push fluid into and out of the control volume subtracts from the total work that the fluid can do on its surroundings.

Answer (score 2):

***Why is shaft work equal to VdP?***

It isn't.

@Chet Miller made me realize that I didn't fully understand your question. Flow work is input to system and is part of the energy that produces shaft work (output). It is not the shaft work itself. It is included as part of the enthalpy entering and exiting a control volume. An example is the input for a turbine that produces shaft work. The following is by way of explanation.

There are basically two forms of thermodynamic work- Boundary work ($PdV$) and flow work ($VdP$).

Boundary work primarily applies to closed thermodynamic systems, that is, systems that do no involve mass transfer with the surroundings. It refers to the expanding or contracting of the system boundaries. The common example used is the expansion or compression of a gas in a cylinder fitted with a piston.

Flow work applies to open systems where there is flow into and out of what is referred to as a "control volume". As @Chet Miller pointed out it is the work done to push fluid into and out of the control volume where a pressure differential exists at the inlet and outlet of the control volume.

The first diagram below shows a generic control volume that accounts for various possible heat and work transfers to or from the control volume, as well as changes in the kinetic and or potential energy of the working fluid into and out of the volume. The flow work is accounted for in the PV term of the entering and exiting enthalpy of the fluid.

The second diagram shows a special case of the first where certain terms are removed  (changes in kinetic and potential energy, and heat transfer) as applied to adiabatic turbines (other than gas turbines), compressors or pumps. For the case of a steam turbine, the turbine work output is simply the change in enthalpy of the steam at the inlet and outlet of the turbine. That enthalpy includes the $VdP$ work needed to push the steam into and out of the turbine.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The flow work is $\dot{m}(P_{out}v_{out}-P_{in}v_{in})$, which represents the work done in pushing fluid out of and into the control volume.

Comment: @Chet Miller Yes but it is my understanding that is included in The entering and exiting enthalpy $h=u+pv$, no?

Comment: Yes.  But that is why the OP is asking why the shaft work (in the absence of dissipation) is equal to VdP.

Comment: @ChetMiller Ah, I think I see the light. The OP thinks flow work IS shaft work.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks Chet for helping me understand the OP question better.

Comment: Moran et al (p 340) and Smith and van Ness (p. 217) show that, if a flow process is being carried out reversibly (within the control volume), the shaft work is equal to $-\int_1^2{vdP}$ (neglecting changes in kinetic energy and potential energy of the working fluid).

Comment: @ChetMiller once again you are way above my level. Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @ChetMiller If not, can you suggest an improvement in my answer?

Comment: I guess the part I object to calling vdP flow work.  Maybe it's just a question of terminology.  I think of the flow work as the d(PV) and the shaft work as the vdP.  I could just be splitting hairs.

Comment: @ChetMiller Hi Chet. I'm having difficulty understanding, for an open system, what role the internal energy component of the enthalpy plays in shaft work, if any. If, according to Moran et al, the shaft work is equal to $-\int_1^2vdP$ (neglecting changes in kinetic and potential energy of the fluid) then it would seem the internal energy component plays no role, at least if =0

Comment: For a differential (small control volume) section of the device, say between axial locations x and x+dx, =-ℎ, where  is the shaft work per unit mass of flowing fluid passing through the control volume and dh is the change in enthalpy per unit mass passing through the control volume. We also have that dh=Tds+vdP. But if the section is operating adiabatic and reversibly, Tds = 0 and dh = vdP. The internal energy is definitely changing. dh=vdP=du+d(Pv). So, for each parcel du=-Pdv.  So the shaft work is dWs=-vdP.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thank you very much for that. What if the fluid is incompressible?

Comment: Even an incompressible fluid can do work on a turbine blade  by pressure forces.  In such a case, the shaft work is equal to $-v\Delta P$.

Comment: @ChetMiller That's what I was thinking. And in that case du=0 since dv=0. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Only for inviscid flow